# version `NSS_3.14.3' not found on Ubuntu 64 bit while running JCEF

Tags: java, chromium-embedded, nss

I have embedded JCEF into my mavan project, I have added all the jar dependencies into mavan. My project is compiled successfully but when I tried to run jar file using command:

> java -Djava.library.path=/home/oes/Desktop/lib/ -jar
>   /home/oes/Desktop/mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am getting error saying :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /home/oes/Desktop/lib/libcef.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so:
>   version `NSS_3.14.3' not found (required by
>   /home/oes/Desktop/lib/libcef.so)

I searched a lot for NSS_3.14.3 but I am not getting what it is? Why it's required? Is it required to be packaged like .so files.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Linux does not have a new enough version of libnss3.so. Installing NSS resolved problem.